# When i save my website on homescreen on android it has a number as an icon

Tags: laravel, favicon

Really weird thing, i used https://realfavicongenerator.net to generate HTML code and all favicon files.

After implementing it I checked everywhere to see if it was right. And it is except on my android when i press the settings (the three dots) and I press "save to homescreen". It just shows a pink background with the letter "1" in it. The pink is actually the color of the usual favicon.

Right now It's not online yet so i can't send a link or anything, but thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Which browser so you use? Actually, only Chrome supports "Add to homescreen" properly. Firefox and built-in browsers tend to ignore the available icons.

Comment: Yeah it's google chrome